# Beginner Question: Wondering why the function needs to be repeated?

Tags: javascript

So I have created a very basic bmi calculator using JS. I have created a function and then tried to recall it using the name of the function (bmiCalculator). From my knowledge this should have given me the correct return.

I looked for and found the solution but would just like to understand why the function needs repeating to run the function?

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {

  var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
  var interpretation;

  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.";
  }

  if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.";
  }

  if (bmi >= 25) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.";
  }

  return interpretation;

};


bmiCalculator(68, 1.73);

function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
  var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
  var interpretation;


  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.";
  }

  if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.";
  }

  if (bmi >= 25) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.";
  }
  return interpretation
};




bmiCalculator(45, 1.65);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need to repeat the function. You should provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, not (or at least not **just**) some working code you don't like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you do not have to repeat function. This code should work fine:

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight,height) {

    var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height,2));
    var interpretation;
    
if (bmi < 18.5) {
    interpretation = "Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.";
}

if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
    interpretation ="Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.";
}

if (bmi >= 25) {
    interpretation ="Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.";
}
   
   return interpretation;
    
};
bmiCalculator(68,1.73);
bmiCalculator(45,1.65);
```

You can save results to variables, for example:

```js
const bmi1 = bmiCalculator(68,1.73);
const bmi2 = bmiCalculator(45,1.65);
console.log(bmi1);
console.log(bmi2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran the code and it works just fine.
You should use console.log and see the ruslts of your code.
In chrome you can press F12 to open the console, then when you use `console.log(bmiCalculator(68,1.73));` it will print the BMI.
you can remove the code after the first function call.